# Schengen 'D' Type Visa will valid of 2 years in 2 Country?

Tags: italy, study, sweden

I got EIT ICT Master Program in 2 Different country.

**I have to complete 1st year in Italy &  2nd year in Sweden.**

I have two option for VISA:

**First:** Initially apply for Italian VISA, later on after reaching in Italy apply for Sweden VISA.

**Second:** Schengen 'D' Type Visa

but I am not sure Schengen 'D' Type Visa, I will get for this much long period.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to expats.

Comment: Visa is for visiting, you need a residence permit.

Comment: The Schengen D category is the national visa.  It allows only short visits to Schengen countries outside the issuing country.  There is, therefore, no way to get a single visa that will allow you to stay for one year in one Schengen country and then a second year in a different Schengen country.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have two options. “D type visa” is one of the names of national visas in Schengen parlance. So an Italian student visa *is* a D-visa as is a Swedish student visa. The only option to stay about one year in several EU countries is to get separate visas (or in some cases residence permits).

Even the EU Blue Card, which is intended to facilitate mobility between participating countries, requires a new authorisation when moving from one country to the other. (It is not applicable to students but I mention it because this is the closest thing to a Schengen residence permit or long-stay visa for third-country nationals there is.)